# How can I make a transparent lock screen for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, lock-screen

Okay I am wondering if there is a solution I can use that incorporates itself into the Windows log off, shutdown, restart, etc... menu.

I am looking for this solution to add in the lock screen option. Not lock screen as in log off but lock screen as in lock the screen and have a password prompt on the screen but you can still see what everything is doing in the background (Useful when scanning the computer).

This would be especially useful on my shared computer because then my family can see my screen when I am scanning but not snoop through my account. Obviously, this solution would need to have an option to also switch users in-case the other user really needs to use the computer and the screen is locked but they don't want to shut it off/restart it.

Is there a solution someone can point me to that can do just this???

Oh yeah btw I would like it to be free (Not a trial)...

Comment: This question is off-topic as questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are not allowed here.

Comment: Ummm yeah there are plenty of questions like this so idk what your talking about... Doesn't matter now I found a program. I understand though...

Comment: Besides, there is no way to do this built-in, so of course achieving this would require software. Duh. Maybe questions that try to do things that aren’t basic and come with the OS are just not welcome here. ◔_◔

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Computer Lock Up](http://www.heise.de/download/computer-lock-up-1113799.html) seems to be exactly, what you are looking for. Its also compatible with Windows 7. Its free.

Comment: FYI: My AV blocks your link and tells me "The web page is on the list of websites with potentially dangerous content."

Comment: @techie007 I dont know why. I can open it without any problems or warnings. Because I use OSX i can't test it. But on different forums there this tool was suggested.
But here another link which hopefully should work: http://www.heise.de/download/computer-lock-up-1113799.html

Comment: @techie007 I'm using SEP and I opened it up fine.

Comment: Websense blocks this link.  It characterizes it as "Potentially malicious/hacking."

Comment: I've changed the link. On this site, there are many other tools. Eventually also some bad tools. But now I've changed the link to a trusted downloading-site. Even if the original link was the link to the creator-site of the tool. But the new download is virus-proofed. It's a german website, but the tool is in english.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know a free alternative, which does the same. You have to invest the 20$. This is quiet cheap. There are many other alternatives which costs around 25$ to 49$.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 lets you use a folder with images as source to an image gallery, you can have only one, alpha-channel only image.